# this.provider.send is not a function

Tags: web3js

I'm trying some examples from the wiki, nothing is working:

```
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/5d4d4f7190b94eb4893ef4dbdc782255"); web3.eth.getBalance("0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1").then(console.log);
```

throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.provider.send is not a function
at s.send (web3.min.js:1)
at _.e [as getBalance] (web3.min.js:1)
at script.js:7
```

And this:

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log);
```

throws this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function
at s.sendAsync (web3.min.js:1)
at _.e [as getBlockNumber] (web3.min.js:1)
at :1:10
```

This isn't the only fuctions that don't work, none of the ones I used worked so far. Directly from the wiki. I'm importing:

Comment: have you tried removing the `Web3.givenProvider ||` statment? Probably an issue with whatever your computer is picking up for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that these docs are quite out of date, I've not seen any usage of `Web3.givenProvider` before. Most sites use `window.web3.currentProvider` for the browser-provided one, and you'll need to instantiate the URL instance with `Web3.providers.HttpProvider`. So you'll probably want to do something like:

```
var web3 = window.web3 ?
  new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider) :
  new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/[infura-id]"));
```

Unfortunately the web3 docs seem to frequently be incorrect and out of date.

Comment: Well, this kinda worked. But, it's as you say. The documentation is really really bad and inaccurate. Just switched to Ethers.js.

Comment: @bruxo00 Can you indicate the page you were following? To try to report and have it fixed.

Comment: Seem to work thanks. I'd remove your infura project's id from the url tho :)

Comment: Good looking out, edited it. I just used the URL in OP's post, though they should remove it as well.